# get value from json in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I have a simple JSON output:

```
"{
   \"max_output_watts\": 150, 
   \"frame_length_inches\": \"62.20\",
   \"frame_width_inches\": \"31.81\"
 }"
```

which I use in a function like so:

```
...
$.getJSON(pop_model_dims_url, {model_id: selected}, function(data, jqXHR){
              alert(data.max_output_watts);
          });
...
```

The alert is just a placeholder for now, but I don't understand why the alert value is 'undefined'. If I do:

```
...
$.getJSON(pop_model_dims_url, {model_id: selected}, function(data, jqXHR){
              alert(data);
          });
...
```

I get the full json dump as expected.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Do you really have the `\"` or is that just how you produce the JSON ?

Comment: @nathanhayfield Huh? If it's JSON you can access it via object notation. Iterate why?

Comment: The `\"` is how the dump is produced using python's json serializer.

Comment: Why do I need to iterate, there is only one row of data?

Comment: to be clear `alert(data)` works and gives me the json output as in the first code line of my question.

Comment: what does `alert(typeof data)` give you?

Comment: only when I try to get a specific value using dot notation do I get the `undefined` value.

Comment: ok - so `alert(typeof(data))` returns string.

Comment: Does the JSON come out like that? Wrapped in quotes? If so, that's your problem.

Comment: @DarwinTech cool, then parse it!

Answer (score 5):

Since your `alert(data);` gives you the full JSON dump, this likely means that the JSON has been *double encoded* on the server.

jQuery will have parsed it once for you, but you'd need to parse it again.

```
$.getJSON(pop_model_dims_url, {model_id: selected}, function(data, jqXHR){
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    alert(data.max_output_watts);
});
```

Of course this is *not a proper fix*. The proper solution is to fix it on the server.

Once you've done that, you won't need `$.parseJSON` anymore.

Comment: Ok this works. So I really have to decode it twice? That sounds weird.

Comment: @DarwinTech: No, that's the point I make at the bottom. There's something wrong on the server side that is encoding it twice. Once you fix that, you won't need to parse it at all, because `$.getJSON` will do it for you.

Comment: gah, so simple its stupid. Give this one the points, they have had their coffee.

Comment: Totally correct. A code error on the server meant there was indeed double encoding duties happening.My bad. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON is probably a string. You have to parse it first. Use

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
alert(obj.max_output_watts);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery getJSON **should** parse the JSON by himself.
If the JSON comes like that:

```
"{
   \"max_output_watts\": 150, 
   \"frame_length_inches\": \"62.20\",
   \"frame_width_inches\": \"31.81\"
 }"
```

The parser mistaken it for a string.

It should come out as plain text like this:

```
{
   "max_output_watts": 150, 
   "frame_length_inches": "62.20",
   "frame_width_inches": "31.81"
 }
```

Comment: Let the down voter explain himself.. (ok, someone must have woken up on the wrong side of the bed today)

Comment: no this is correct - and confirmed above, whoever DV'd you missed the bus on this one.

Comment: Well, Thanks a lot for fixing the rank :)

Comment: I didn't downvote but this answer came 5 minutes before other saying the same (and adding a solution). It's useless in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You have to parse to JSON, because it looks like not a json, since the method is undefined:

Here is the notation with jQuery:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);

data.max_output_watts;
```

And here is how you should do without:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);

data.max_output_watts;
```

Regards!